# How can I get the local time modification of a file with File::stat in perl?

Tags: perl, datetime

How can I get the file modification time formatted in local time?

By doing this:

```
use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%Y%m%d%H%M';

print Time::Piece->strptime(stat($ARGV[0])->mtime, '%s')->strftime($format);
```

I get `202011301257` for a file that was saved at Nov 30 13:57 in my local time (GMT+01:00).

Since I can do

```
print localtime $file->stat->mtime;
```

and

```
print localtime->strftime($format)
```

I'd like to do something like

```
print (localtime stat($file)->mtime)->strftime($format);
```

Which throws

```
Can't locate object method "mtime" via package "1" (perhaps you forgot to load "1"?)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to do something like

> ```
> print (localtime stat($file)->mtime)->strftime($format);
> ```

Very close! Your first parenthesis is in the wrong spot:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; # Pardon the boilerplate
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%Y%m%d%H%M';
say localtime(stat($ARGV[0])->mtime)->strftime($format);
```

Comment: Re "*Your first parenthesis is in the wrong spot*", That's not actually the problem. The placement of the parenthesis is correct. The problem is that the omitted parens around print are required here because `print (...)->strftime($format);` means `( print(...) )->strftime($format);`

Answer (score 1):

**Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.** It would have caught the problem:

```
print (...) interpreted as function at a.pl line 6.
```

---

You have the following

```perl
print ( localtime ... )->strftime($format);
```

Because the space between `print` and `(` is meaningless, the above is equivalent to the following:

```perl
( print( localtime ... ) )->strftime($format);
```

The problem is that you are using `->strftime` on the result of `print`. The problem goes away if you don't omit the parens around `print`'s operands.

```perl
print( ( localtime ... )->strftime($format) );
```

Alternatively, not omitting the parens `localtime`'s args would allow you to remove the parens causing the problem.

```perl
print localtime( ... )->strftime($format);
```